# Problem understanding Maclaurin series derivation of Euler's identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Assuming:

$p(x)=f(0)+f'(0)(x)+f''(0)(x^2/2!)+f'''(0)(x^3/3!)+...+f^{(n)}(0)(x^n/n!)+...$

(i.e. the Maclaurin series expansion function)

Assuming the standard results for:

$f(x)=e^x\\ f(x)=cos(x)\\ f(x)=sin(x)$

Let:

$z=x+jy\\f(z)=f(x+jy)$

Let:

$x=0\implies\\z=jy\implies\\f(z)=f(jy)$

And let:

$f(z)=e^{jy},f(0)=1\implies\\f'(z)=je^{jy},f'(0)=j\implies\\f''(z)=-e^{jy}, f''(0)=-1\implies\\f'''(z)=-je^{jy},f'''(0)=-j...$

...etc.

Recall:

$z=jy$

And:

$f(z)=e^{jy}$

Therefore:

$p(z)=f(0)+f'(0)(jy)+f''(0)((jy)^2/2!)+f'''(0)((jy)^3/3!)+...+f^n(0)((jy)^n/n!)+...\implies\\p(z)=f(0)+f'(0)(z)+f''(0)((z)^2/2!)+f'''(0)((z)^3/3!)+...+f^{(n)}(0)((z)^n/n!)+...\implies\\p(z)=(1)+(j)(z)+(-1)((z)^2/2!)+(-j)((z)^3/3!)+...+f^{(n)}(0)((z)^n/n!)+...$

I keep running into this mistake:

$p(z)=1+j(z)-((z)^2/2!)-j((z)^3/3!)+...\implies$

$p(z)=1+j(jy)-((jy)^2/2!)-j((jy)^3/3!)+...\implies$

$p(z)=1-y+(y^2/2!)-(y^3/3!)+...$

I can see that this is wrong, but I can't see why. Please help!

Comment: your problem is with parentheses; if you write: $p(z)=f(0)+f'(0)(jy)+f''(0)((jy)^2/2!)+f'''(0)((jy)^3/3!)+...+f^n(0)((jy)^n/n!)+...$ there will be no longer problems

Comment: Near the end, you say "Where '$f^n(0)$' is supposed to read as..." but on the line right above it, you have:$$p(z)=f(0)+f'(0)(jy)+f''(0)(jy^2/2!)+\dots$$when it should be:$$p(z)=f(0)+f'(0)(z)+f''(0)(z^2/2!)+\dots$$where $z=jy$.  For example,$$z^2=(jy)^2=-y^2$$Do you see what went wrong?

Comment: I am a bit slow at this. Thanks for your replies, will take me a little time to think through.

Comment: No problem!  Glad to help :D

Comment: Thank you very much. That was giving me no end of grief. @JeanMarie and SBA

Comment: You know what, it's *still* giving me grief. There are a couple of edits, I suppose that was always going to happen, for eg that first $jy$ should read $j(jy)$ in the penultimate expression. I can edit that out. The typographical error (the missing parentheses) is accepted with thanks. That is an error in the asking of the question. I will edit that.

Comment: So now, using $z=jy$ such that $z^2=(jy)^2=-y^2$, we can see that the first term in the Maclaurin expansion of $e^{jy}$ is $f(0)$ which is, of course, $1$. The second term is $f'(0)(jy)$ which is the same as saying $j(jy)$ which is equal to $-y$. The third term, following this pattern, is $f''(0)((jy)^2/2!)$ which equates to $-1((jy)^2/2!)$ which is the same as $-1(-y^2/2!)$ which is, finally, $(y^2/2!)$... This *can't* be right. This is the series expansion of $e^{jy}$ we're talking about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a summation operator:

$$e^{jx}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(jx)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty j^k\frac{x^k}{k!}.$$

The even powers of $j$ are alternatively $\pm1$, and the odd ones $\pm j$. Then

$$\Re e^{jx}=\cos x=\sum_{l=0}^\infty(-1)^l\frac{x^{2l}}{(2l)!}$$

and

$$\Im e^{jx}=\sin x=\sum_{l=0}^\infty(-1)^l\frac{x^{2l+1}}{(2l+1)!}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm not entirely sure how to relate your answer to the question. I'm aware that $\Re e^{jx}=\cos x$ and $\Im e^{jx}=\sin x$, but when I try to build this up from the Maclaurin series, I get the above botched result. Also, shouldn't the imaginary case you highlight have $\sum_{l=0}^\infty(-1)^l\frac{x^{2l-1}}{(2l-1)!}$? Otherwise how do you get the correct power for the case where $l=1$?

Comment: @user401185: no, the formula with $-1$ is meaningless for $l=0$.

Comment: Oh yeah. Hah, I get you. I'm not familiar with that notation. Can you help me see how this relates to the problem I have outlined please?

Comment: @user401185: $e^{jx}=\cos x+j\sin x$.

Comment: I get that $e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ and I get that this works because, really, $e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(x-0)^k$ and because the derivative of $e^x$ wrt $x$ is $e^x$ and that $e^0=1$. However, the derivative of $e^{jx}$ is not $e^{jx}$. So I guess I'm asking, "what happens to the '$f^{(k)}(0)$' term in the case where $f(x)=e^{jx}$?" Only I changed the variable to $jy$ to avoid the inevitable confusion over terms.

Comment: Also, it's not a function of $x$, which is why I phrased it as $f(z)$ where $z=x+jy$ and $x=0$

Comment: @user401185: the $k^{th}$ derivative of $e^{jx}$ is $j^ke^{jx}$, i.e. $j^k$ when taken at $0$. Alternatively, in the usual series for $e^z$, $z$ can by any complex number. Both formulations appear in my first line.

Comment: If:  
$e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(x-0)^k\implies$  
$e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(x)^k\implies$  
$e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$  

Then:  
$e^{jy}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(jy-0)^k\implies$  
$e^{jy}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{j^{k}}{k!}(jy)^k\implies$  
$e^{jy}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{j^{k}(jy)^k}{k!}$  

Just to be clear, I'm *not* arguing this is true! I can't see why it doesn't follow. And thanks again for your time and help. I also don't have enough rep to chat, sorry.

Comment: @user401185: no, either your variable is $y$ and you derive on $y$, or your variable is $z=jy$ and you derive on $z$. In no case will you have $j^k$ duplicated.

Comment: Do you mean something like:  

$e^{z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(z-0)^k\implies$  
$e^{z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{j^{k}}{k!}(z)^k\implies$  
$e^{z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{j^{k}(z)^k}{k!}$  

? Sorry, I know this must be frustrating to explain.

Comment: @PMBY: where is this $j$ coming from ???

Comment: In the Maclaurin series expansion formula (with respect to $z=x+jy$, $x=0$), each term in the series is represented in the form $\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(z-0)^k$. Given the function $e^z$, we know that the $\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$ part of the term is equivalent to $\frac{j^k}{k!}$. The $(z-0)^k$ part is $(z)^k$. Putting these together we get $\frac{j^k(z)^k}{k!}$ for each term. I can see that this is obviously wrong. What's going on?

Comment: @PMBY: what is $f^{(k)}(z)$ ? Then what is $f^{(k)}(0)$ ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. $f^{(k)}(0)$ is the $k$th derivative of the function $f(z)$ at the value $z=0$. $f^{(k)}(z)$ is, I suppose, the $k$th derivative of $f(z)$.

$f(z)=e^{jy},f(0)=1\implies\\f'(z)=je^{jy},f'(0)=j\implies\\f''(z)=-e^{jy}, f''(0)=-1\implies\\f'''(z)=-je^{jy},f'''(0)=-j$

Comment: @PMBY: no, I am asking the derivatives of $e^z$ wrt $z$.

Comment: If $z$ is real, then the differentials of $e^z$ are all $e^z$. In this case, $z=jy$. Do we treat complex $z$ as real for the purpose of differentiation?

Comment: @PMBY: the property holds for complex as well.

Comment: So is the first derivative of $e^{jy}$ equal to $je^{jy}$? I was treating $e^z$ as $e^{jy}$ where $z=jy$.

Comment: @PMBY: on what variable are you differentiating ?

Comment: I was assuming $d/dz[f(z)]$ where $z=x+jy$. Are you saying, in this case, that $d/dz[e^z]=e^z$? If that is the case, how is it that we substitute $z=jy$ back into the $(z-0)^k$ term but leave it as $z$ in the $f^{(k)}(0)$ term when finalising the $sin$ and $cos$ series for $e^{jy}=cos\ (y)+j\ sin\ (y) $? (Thank you very much for your time and effort here! Massively appreciated).

Comment: @PMBY: yes, in all cases $(e^z)'=e^z$. And of course, for $z=0$, $e^z=1$. This leads to the first summation in my answer. If you work with $y$ instead of $z$, you get the second summation. From the beginning, you have been confusing $iy$ and $y$.

Comment: What I don't get is how we can say $e^{jy}=e^{z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(z)^k$ while keeping $z$ effectively as a real. Doesn't that take us to $e^{z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(z)^k$ with $z$ being treated as a real? Or, to put it another way, once we have this equation, if we substitute $z=jy$ back in, how is the $\frac{1}{k!}$ term still valid? Since $e^z=e^{jy}$ and $\frac{d}{dy}\ e^{jy}=je^{jy}$. Aren't we effectively saying $e^z=e^{jy}, e^z=je^{jy}, e^z=-e^{jy}$ and $e^z=-je^{jy}$?

Comment: So the important difference here is that $\frac{d}{dy}\ e^{jy}$ is not equal to $\frac{d}{dz}\ e^{z}$ where $z=x+jy, x=0$?

Comment: @PMBY: for the last time, $y\ne iy$. You are too much focused on your theory. Read what I write.

Comment: There is no theory. I am struggling to understand a basic concept. Thank you for your time and help. I believe, in my preceeding comment, I pretty much came to the conclusion you have been driving me towards.

Comment: @PMBY: mh I am afraid you didn't understand my last comment either. I quit.